# EDIT TEXT - ANDROID

Tags: android, edittext

Tenho 3 edit texts no meu projeto, setei o máximo d caracteres para cada um, eu gostaria de saber como fazer pra quando esse atingir o máximo ele dê foco para outro. Ex: o primeiro tem no max 2, aí digito 10 e ele já dá foco pro próximo edit text.

Comment: Basicamente como o Carlos Rafael respondeu, mas precisa buscar o limite do editText para comparar usando o `lentgh()`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069015/how-to-get-edittext-maxlength-setting-in-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar um TextWatcher, conforme o usuário vai digitando você vai checando o tamanho da string, quando chegar no length limite você muda o foco para outro edittext.

```
public class YourClass extends Activity {

 private EditText yourEditText;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        yourEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditTextId);

        yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

          public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            // you can call or do what you want with your EditText here
            SE tamanho = tamanhoLimite ENTAO
               muda o foco
            FIMSE

          }

          public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

          public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
       });
    }

}
```

Você pode dar uma olhada nesse outro tópico aqui, que foi de onde tirei o trecho de código acima: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134144/android-edittext-onchange-listener